# Upper bound of eigenvalues of a matrix $(A + B)^{-1} B$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, singular-values

Consider a positive-definite matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and a positive semi-definite matrix $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, and consider the $i$-th largest eigenvalue of $(A + B)^{-1} B$. I know all eigenvalues of this matrix are less than 1, and is it possible to obtain a non-trivial upper bound on $\lambda_i(A + B)^{-1} B)$ that is less than 1?

I've tried Weyl's inequality and a conclusion from Bathias' "Matrix Analysis" that says, for any two operators $A, B$ on Hilbert space $H$ with dimension $n$, for all $i, j$ such that $i+j \leq n+1,  \lambda_{i+j-1}(A B) \leq \lambda_i(A) \lambda_j(B)$, where $\lambda_i(A)$ is the $i$-th largest eigenvalue of $A$. But the bound I obtain in terms of the eigenvalues of $A$, $B$ is trivial - the bound I obtain may be larger than 1.

Any help is greatly appreiciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $B=\pmatrix{B_1&0\\ 0&0}$ and $A=\pmatrix{X&Y^T\\ Y&Z}$, where $B_1$ is an $r\times r$ positive definite matrix. Then
$$
(A+B)^{-1}B
=\pmatrix{(B_1+S)^{-1}&\ast\\ \ast&\ast}\pmatrix{B_1&0\\ 0&0}
=\pmatrix{(I+SB_1^{-1})^{-1}&0\\ \ast&0},
$$
where $S=X-Y^TZ^{-1}Y$ the Schur complement of $Z$ in $A$. Therefore, when $i,j,k\in\{1,2,\ldots,r\}$ and $i+j=k+1$,
\begin{align}
\lambda^{\downarrow}_k\left((A+B)^{-1}B\right)
&=\frac{1}{1+\lambda^{\uparrow}_k(SB_1^{-1})}
=\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{1}{\lambda^{\downarrow}_k(S^{-1}B_1)}}\\
&\le\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{1}{\lambda^{\downarrow}_i(S^{-1})\lambda^{\downarrow}_j(B_1)}}\\
&\le\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{1}{\lambda^{\downarrow}_i(A^{-1})\lambda^{\downarrow}_j(B_1)}}
=\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{\lambda^{\uparrow}_i(A)}{\lambda^{\downarrow}_j(B)}}
\end{align}
where the first inequality is the one mentioned in your question and the second one is due to the fact that $S^{-1}$ is a principal submatrix of $A^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you! One question: why can we assume B has the form $\begin{bmatrix} B_1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$? I understand we can have a matrix of this form (let $B' = \begin{bmatrix} B_1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$) with the same eigenvalues of a positive definite $B$ and but I don't know why $(A + B')^{-1} B'$ would necessarily have the same eigenvalues as $(A + B)^{-1} B$. Could you clarify?

Comment: @Yang You can orthogonally diagonalise $B$ and apply the same similarity transform to $A$.

Comment: Yes I understand diagonalization could give us the diagonal form, but I wonder whether the sum of $\begin{bmatrix} B_1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0  \end{bmatrix}$ and $A$ would still have the same eigenvalues as $A+B$

Comment: @Yang If you apply the same similarity transform to $A$, the eigenvalues certainly remain unchanged. This is just a change of basis for both linear operators.

Comment: I am sorry that I still do not get it. Say I have $B = P D P^{\top}$, then are you saying $\lambda(A+B) = \lambda(PAP^{\top} + P D P^{\top})$? (And I understand $\lambda(PAP^{\top} + P D P^{\top}) = \lambda(A+D)$)

Comment: @Yang Huh? No. Suppose $B=QB'Q^T$ is an orthogonal diagonalisation. Define $A'$ by $A=QA'Q^T$. Now call $B'$ and $A'$ the new $B$ and the new $A$. Then the old $A+B$ is similar to the new $A+B$.

Comment: My understanding is that $B'$ is diagonal, and $A'$ may not be diagonal, as in fact $A' = Q^{\top} A Q$ and $A$ may not be diagonal. I can see $B' = Q^{\top} B Q$, so $A' + B' = Q^{\top} A Q + Q^{\top} B Q = Q^{\top} (A+B) Q$, so $\lambda(A' + B') = \lambda(A+B)$ - is this what you mean?

Comment: @Yang Yes.$\phantom{}$

Comment: @Yang $\lambda^\downarrow_i$ denotes the $i$-th **largest** eigenvalue. In the linked answer, $\lambda_i$ denotes the $i$-th smallest eigenvalue (which is denoted by $\lambda^\uparrow_i$ here). In other words, $\lambda^\downarrow_i(X)=-\lambda^\uparrow_i(-X)$.

Comment: You are right! I deleted my comment before I saw your reply because I figured that out. Thank you!